# Fatal Error with message 'Class 'himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptchaValidator' not found'

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to implement recaptcha for my project written in PHP and Yii2 and I'm using [himiklab's](https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget) widget. 
I tried to follow the steps mentioned in the Readme File but I couldnt get it working.

I tried adding the widget rule in composer.json file and did a composer update on terminal and I see this as below.
[image]

I even tried to install it using composer using `composer require --prefer-dist "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" "*"` and I get the same error as above image.

My code:
Signup form.php

```
 public function rules() { 
    return [ ... 
  [['reCaptcha'],\himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptchaValidator::SignupForm(), 'secret' => 'secretkey', 'uncheckedMessage' => 'Please confirm that you are not a bot.'] 
    ]; 
    }
```

signup.php (view)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'reCaptcha')->widget(\himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptcha::SignupForm(),['siteKey' => 'sitekey']) ?>
```

main.php

```
return [ 
'components' => [ 'reCaptcha' => [ 'name' => 'reCaptcha', 'class' => 'himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptcha', 'siteKey' => 'siteKey', 'secret' => 'secretKey', ], 
... 
]
```

When I ignored the installation of widget using composer and continued with  adding the widget in composer.json file `"himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" : "*"` and running the application, I see the error mentioned in the heading.

Did anyone face the same issue? Can someone help me in solving this. TIA

Comment: Those errors look unrelated to the recaptcha package you're talking about

Comment: @RobbieAverill Yeah. even I thought so. But I'm seeing this in my console when I'm trying to install the widget using composer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to install the fxp-asset plugin:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672628/6392794. There is the same problem with composer

Comment: It didnt help. I tried to do the same but the problem still exits. I'm in my project folder and then try to do composer update or version after running the code above and it shows the same error. Please find the [image](https://ibb.co/d95OdR) here

Comment: Did you try following instructions: 1. remove `vendor/` and composer.lock. 2. Remove the global plugin with  `composer global remove "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"`. 3. Remove `.composer` directory in your homedir. 4. If your `composer.json` has `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*"` remove it. 5. After these run `composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins`.

Comment: If you can not solve this problem, use [asset-packagist](https://asset-packagist.org) instead of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`. It is faster and easier than composer-asset-plugin. Remove `"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
      "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
      "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
  }, ` from your composer.json and add here repositories section: 
  `"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
  ],`. After these add `'@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset'` to your config's aliases section.